# Foundation - vertically align middle

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation v6.2.1 and I am trying to vertically align `h3` elements to middle, but I am not suceeding. How am I suppose to do that?

```
<div class='large-12 columns most-read'>
  <div class='large-1 columns align-self-middle'>
    <h3> {{ orderNumber }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='large-10 columns'>
    <p>{{ Article title }}</p>
    <br>
    <p>{{ Article summary }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class='large-1 columns text-center align-self-middle'>
    <h3>{{ numberOfViews }}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `line-height` option to vertically align text elements in the middle.

Set the `div` to some height and set your `h3` element's `line-height` to the same unit.

```
.align-self-middle
{
 height:100px;
}

.align-self-middle h3
{
  line-height:100px;
}
```

You can now see your text aligned in the middle - vertically.

Comment: That's great until you have a line break in your `h3`.  The line-height then means a big gap between the lines.

Answer (score 1):

The `.align-self-middle` class is included in the foundation-flex version and it is not available in other version. Your code looks okay and it should work.

See the working example.
http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/xOKorV